# How to rename files useing Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filenames, file-rename

Can anyone recommend a good solution to recursively remove unwanted letters  in file names 
remove

```
.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM]
```

For example:

```
 Yellow Submarine (1968) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]
│   ├── www.YTS.AM.jpg
│   └── Yellow.Submarine.1968.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4
├── You Might Be The Killer (2018) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]
│   ├── www.YTS.AM.jpg
│   └── You.Might.Be.The.Killer.2018.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4
├── Your Name (2016) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]
│   ├── www.YTS.AM.jpg
│   └── Your.Name.2016.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4
```

becomes:

```
 Yellow Submarine (1968) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]
│   ├── www.YTS.AM.jpg
│   └── Yellow.Submarine.1968.mp4
├── You Might Be The Killer (2018) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]
│   ├── www.YTS.AM.jpg
│   └── You.Might.Be.The.Killer.2018.mp4
├── Your Name (2016) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]
│   ├── www.YTS.AM.jpg
│   └── Your.Name.2016.mp4
```

Comment: What is your logic here. What is "Unwanted letters". Please explain the logic you used, as a human, to decide what to remove/change in each of these file names. Do you have any code you are struggling with or are you looking for a developer?

Comment: i want to remove ''' 720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM] ''' from """" Yellow.Submarine.1968.720p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4 "" becomes just Yellow.Submarine.1968.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Since the string being removed appears to be the same for each file then you can use `find` and `rename` to solve this:

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/\.720p\.BluRay\.x264\-\[YTS\.AM\]//' '{}' \;
```

Run that in whatever the base directory is that holds these folders and it should clean the files up.

To test first you can use the `-n` flag on that rename command to see what it will do if you allow it to act (without the `-n` flag):

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/\.720p\.BluRay\.x264\-\[YTS\.AM\]//' '{}' \;
```